# React native blank screen after generating APK

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native, and everything was working well while I was developing, but, when I built the APK (using this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) and installed it on my device, the app shows just a blank page.
Did anybody had the same issue?

Edit:
I looked at the log on the device, and this is the error:

> 11-09 22:00:51.115 16525 16525 W unknown:React: You seem to be running on device. Run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward the debug server's port to the device.
>   11-09 22:00:51.115 16525 16525 W unknown:React: You seem to be running on device. Run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward the debug server's port to the device.
>   11-09 22:00:51.198 16525 16555 E ReactNative: Got JS Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue by running the following command before building:

> curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o
>   "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for how to generate signed apk.

it seem you did not have a react.gradle file under android/app: 
you can bundle the JavaScript package and drawable resources manually by doing the following in a terminal:

```
$ mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

after following this process app.release.apk will be under android\app\build\outputs\apk directory.