# React native blank screen on signed APK release

Tags: android, react-native

I am using Android 6.0 and react-native 0.39.2. I had no issues during development, but when I build and run the signed .apk following the official documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), there appears only a blank screen on both emulator and my device. I have also checked and applied the solutions for the same issue: [React native blank screen after generating APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617099/react-native-blank-screen-after-generating-apk). Running the following commands:

```
$ mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file 
index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

or

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

before building with

```
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

did not solve the problem. I also checked the device logs and there seems to be no errors:

```
03-26 16:35:44.950 11586 11613 I ReactNativeJS: Running application 
"lycapp" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === 
false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations 
are ON
```

Is there anyone having similar issues?

Comment: Instead of asking 'Is there anyone having similar issues?', try any crash report tool(google play integrated, firebase, acra, crashalytics) to get the stacktrace, show the stacktrace in the question and ask "how can I fix this?"(assuming the stacktrace isn't easy to solve)(assuming there is a stacktrace)

Comment: @LunarWatcher Is there any way to get the stacktrace without using a 3rd party tool?

Comment: If there is no crash, no. You may have a try/catch somewhere that prevents it. I don't know about the rest of the tools, but ACRA throws an exception if there are critical errors(e.g. runtime(nullpointer, etc) that are caught so you get the stacktrace even if the app doesn't crash(assuming there is something that generates a stacktrace)

Comment: If there is a stacktrace, you still have no idea where it is generated and as such you cannot display it using for an instance a dialog or toast. That is why the third party tools come in: No matter where the exception is, they will find it and give it to you

Comment: @MertOvn , had you overcome this issue?

Comment: The same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47932341/3332734